# Unknown label type: 'continuous' while using random forest classifier on a multi class classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

My code:

```
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=600, min_samples_split=25)
rf_classifier.fit(combined_x_train, y_train)
```

The error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3f817939cbaa> in <module>
      1 rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=600, min_samples_split=25)
----> 2 rf_classifier.fit(combined_x_train, y_train)
      3 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    329         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    330 
--> 331         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
    332 
    333         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
    557 
    558     def _validate_y_class_weight(self, y):
--> 559         check_classification_targets(y)
    560 
    561         y = np.copy(y)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    181     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    182                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 183         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    184 
    185 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

y_train is a NumPy array with values between 0 and 5 for multi-class classification with each class corresponding to an integer number.

The type of y_train is int32.

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you confirm that your targets are what you really intended for? Unknown label type: errors occur when there is a problem in y_train at the time of fit. Check if there are any floating-point numbers in your labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might occur when y_train is not of the type that is inputted into any classifier model. In this case, y_train was of the type Series. When I changed the type to a NumPy array, it worked fine.
Here's the code:

```
y_train = y_train.to_numpy(dtype="int")
y_test = y_test.to_numpy(dtype="int")
```